# I want to perform $pull, $slice and $inc together in Mongodb Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, backend

```
[
  {
    "_id": "64a5a6fb80a26800e9b7d885",
    "userId": "123456789",
    "transactions": [
      {
        "title": "title_1",
        "price": 40,
        "_id": "64a5bcbc4c28d90fdfc5c067"
      },
      {
        "title": "title_2",
        "price": 40,
        "_id": "64a5bcbc4c28d90fdfc5c068"
      },
      {
        "title": "title_3",
        "price": 40,
        "_id": "64a5bcbc4c28d90fdfc5c064"
      },
      {
        "title": "title_4",
        "price": 40,
        "_id": "64a5bcbc4c28d90fdfc5c061"
      },
      {
        "title": "title_5",
        "price": 40,
        "_id": "64a5bcbc4c28d90fdfc5c060"
      },
    ],
    chart_data:{
         "2022": [
                   {label:"Jan", value:500},
                   {label:"Feb", value:500},
                   {label:"March", value:500},  
                  {label:"April", value:500}
                 ],
         "2023": [
                   {label:"Jan", value:500},
                   {label:"Feb", value:500},
                   {label:"March", value:500},  
                  {label:"April", value:500}
                 ]
    },
    "createdAt": "2023-07-05T17:23:07.738Z",
    "updatedAt": "2023-07-08T16:05:31.249Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

So,
whenever user call api i am getting payload like {userId:"123456789", transactionId:"64a5bcbc4c28d90fdfc5c067", label:"Jan", year:"2022"}

1st) I want to delete transactionId(in this case it is title_1) from transaction array.
2nd) then I want to slice last two element from the updated transaction array.
3rd) I also want to Minues price(transactionId price) from the chart_data object by specific year provided by api payload.

and then return the updated transaction array after slice last two item and updated chart_data object.

Comment: Do you want only to return it, or do you want to change the document on the db as well?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, and you just want to update this document and return the updated document, one option is:

```
const updatePipeline = [
  {$set: {
      transactions: {$slice: [
          {$filter: {
              input: "$transactions",
              cond: {$ne: ["$$this._id", payload.transactionId]}
          }},
          {$subtract: [{$size: "$transactions"}, 3]}
      ]},
      priceToReduce: {$first: {$filter: {
            input: "$transactions",
            cond: {$eq: ["$$this._id", payload.transactionId]}
      }}}
  }},
  {$set: {
      `chart_data.${payload.year}`: {
        $reduce: {
          input: `$chart_data.${payload.year}`,
          initialValue: [],
          in: {$concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              {$cond: [
                  {$eq: ["$$this.label", payload.label]},
                  [{
                      label: payload.label,
                      value: {$subtract: ["$$this.value", "$priceToReduce.price"]}
                  }],
                  ["$$this"]
              ]}
          ]}
        }
      },
      priceToReduce: "$$REMOVE"
  }}
]

const res = await db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
  {userId: payload.userId},
  updatePipeline,
  {returnNewDocument: true}
);
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5khAK1RT2iN)

Comment: yes I also want to update the database but after update the database I want only last two transaction from transaction array and in chart_data i only want specific object(like in this case i only want 2022 object)

Comment: I'm not familiar with a way to do both on the same query. If you want a query that updates the db, it can return the updated document or the original document, not a subset of the updated document. If you want a subset, you can do it in another query, or by filtering with your code on the updated result returned from the first query.

Comment: ok can we do $pull and $slice at a same time like i want to remove particular transaction from transaction array and then return last 5 result from the transaction array.

Comment: without updating the db?

Comment: with updating the db, as i saw on mongoose docs there is a method where we can $push and $slice together with db even i am using this in my code but now i also want something like this but this time it should be $pull and $slice